# When can 'am' be used before a verb?

Tags: expressions, verbs

Like the famous quote, 'Now I am become death, destroyer of world' when is it allowed to use 'am' before any verb?

Comment: You can't use 'am' before _any_ verb. 'Is become' is a special usage - see the linked questions.

Comment: I know it is not allowed in general use. But I have seen the use of 'am' in this unorthodox manner in multiple places. That's why I am asking when is this allowed?